# Html: Text is not under table but it should be

Tags: html, text, html-table, alignment

I'm not an HTML expert but I'm curios about what happens.

The imagines with link should be under the table, but it's not, and I dont know why.

The table align is not left, so my code sees to be good.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>
Statistiche</TITLE>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
#postString{ visibility:hidden}
</style>
<style>
#location{ visibility:hidden}
</style>
<style>
#porta{ visibility:hidden}
</style>
<style>
#anno{ visibility:hidden}
</style>
<style>
#tempoms{ visibility:hidden}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="postString">
8
</div>
<div id="location">
localhost
</div>
<div id="porta">
9080
</div>
<div id="tempoms">
10000
</div>
<div id="anno">
2018
</div>
<form action="Settings">
Timeout [ms]:<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="tempoms" 
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value ="1"
<input type="hidden" name="idquery" value ="9"
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<a href=UtenteServlet> Return</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<TABLE  class="fixed" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" align="bottom">
<style> caption {padding: 5px;text-align: left; font-size:160%}</style>
 <caption> Fatturato mese per mese</caption>
<TR VALIGN="bottom">
 <TH ROWSPAN="3" VALIGN="middle">Fatturato<BR>Mese</TH>
 <TD class="bottom" HEIGHT="200"><IMG SRC="Img/verde.jpg"  width="100" HEIGHT="124"></TD>
 <TD class="bottom" HEIGHT="200"><IMG SRC="Img/verde.jpg"  width="100" HEIGHT="200"></TD>
 <TD class="bottom" HEIGHT="200"><IMG SRC="Img/verde.jpg"  width="100" HEIGHT="197"></TD>
 <TD class="bottom" HEIGHT="200"><IMG SRC="Img/verde.jpg"  width="100" HEIGHT="150"></TD>
 <TD class="bottom" HEIGHT="200"><IMG SRC="Img/verde.jpg"  width="100" HEIGHT="20"></TD>
</TR>
 <TR>
  <TD> 1  </TD>
  <TD> 11  </TD>
  <TD> 111  </TD>
  <TD> 1111  </TD>
  <TD> 11111  </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Gennaio </TD>
<TD>Febbraio </TD>
<TD>Marzo </TD>
<TD>Aprile </TD>
<TD>Maggio </TD>
 </TR>  
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p align="bottom">
<a href=http://localhost:9080/HydroGui/Scroll?direzione=indietro> <img border="0" alt="back" src="Img/backward.png" width="100" height="100" align="left"> 
<a href=http://localhost:9080/HydroGui/Settings?id=1&tempoms=-1> <img border="0" alt="pause" src="Img/pausa.png" width="100" height="100"  align="left"> 
<a href=http://localhost:9080/HydroGui/Scroll?direzione=avanti> <img border="0" alt="next" src="Img/forward.png" width="100" height="100"  align="left"> 
</p>
</BODY>
<script src="redirect.js" >
</script>
</HTML>
```

It doesn't matter if you don't see any imagine in the table, the focus is why the Img/pausa.png and the other 2 imagines are over the table and not under it.

Comment: Fix all your invalid html (there is a lot of errors) and see if that fixes the problem - my guess is it will.  Also why so many style tags - why not just merged them all into within your stylesheet or just one style tag.  A big tip is properly indent your code so you can match start and end tags

Comment: Accept one of the answers, so this question will be closed, and people won't think it's still not solved

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't close the `<TABLE>` with `</TABLE>` before the images. The behavior of table s such that they will be placed left to the table stuff.

Comment: Ok, my Editor does not inform me about the error, so I look around for solutions where solution was so easy.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `table` before the images , without closing it, everything you write after the opening tag,  will be inside it

And you didn't close the `a` tags either actually